# explain internally how split and contains methods works for String

Tags: java, string

I just did some work around and suprised by the result. Let me explain it.

```
String str = "aaa.jpg";
String[] str1 = str.split(".");  //output of this is empty array with size 0
str.contains("."); //output of this is true.
```

can anyone explain, why `split()` method unable to recognize the `"."`, where as `contains()` can recognize the `"."`.

Comment: -1 no research effort. Simply looking at the javadocs would have told you split uses regex and contains does not.

Comment: @ColinD i don't have idea that in regex if we use "." gives empty, this is not the ignorance, but lack of knowledge. I havent worked on regex so, without knowledge and experience no one is perfect. Also plesae donot expect everyone is as perfect as you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) works with regular expressions, and [`.` in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) means *any* character (except newline characters). Furthermore, the reason the resulting array is empty is because `split()` discards trailing empty strings (you can have it keep empty strings by providing a negative second argument, however):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

It is possible to escape the `.` to match literal periods:

```
str.split("\\.")
```

By contrast, [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) works with literal strings, so a `.` is just a `.`.

Comment: is there a good reason to escape the string manually, instead of using Pattern.quote() ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, even if contains matched for regular expressions, contains(".") would still give you true

Comment: @ColinD If you know what the regex/string is going to be beforehand I find escaping manually to be more clear. If you want to split on an unknown string (e.g. a string you read from the user), then `Pattern.quote()` would be used.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is a special character for regular expressions.
If you want to literally match `.` then you should do:

```
str.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc for [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Javadoc for [String#contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). One uses regex, the other doesn't.

The `.` character in regex means any character. You can look at the java rules for regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). The literal escape for a character is `\x` where `x` is the character. Because we are using Java String literals, we need to also escape the `\`, so

```
"yourString".split("\\.");
```

or use the [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method.

`contains()` is implemented as

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
    return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
}
```

where `indexOf` finds the first occurence of the specified `CharSequence`, in this case the single character `'.'`.